# Unexpected token { when getting data from Flask to a JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I'm trying to get some GPS data from a .py file onto an HTML. The data are two arrays of latitudes and longitudes. I want to load data from the python file into arrays of lats and lngs and make markers on a google map. I get an error at: `var lats = {{ templateData["latitudes"]|safe }};`. I even tried quotation marks, not writing safe and using JSON.parse(); with |safe. Any help would be appreciated.

gpsquery.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)
import sqlite3

def getData():
  latitudes = list()
  longitudes = list()
  altitudes =list()
  conn=sqlite3.connect('C:/webenvironment/gpsdata.db')
  curs=conn.cursor()
  for row in curs.execute('SELECT * FROM GPSDATA'):
    latitudes.append(row[0])
    longitudes.append(row[1])
    altitudes.append(row[2])
    
    
  conn.close()
  return latitudes, longitudes, altitudes
  
  
@app.route("/")
def index():
  latitudes, longitudes, altitudes = getData()
  templateData = {'latitudes': latitudes, 'longitudes': longitudes,'altitudes': altitudes}
  return render_template('index.html', templateData=templateData)    
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(debug=True)
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>My Google Map</title>
    <style>
      #map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      
      function initMap(){
        var lats = {{ templateData["latitudes"]|safe }};
        var lngs = {{ templateData["longitudes"]|safe }};
        
        
        console.log(lats.toString());
        
        var centerLat = (Math.max.apply(null,lats) + Math.min.apply(null,lats))/2;
        var centerLng = (Math.max.apply(null,lngs) + Math.min.apply(null,lngs))/2;
        
        
        var options = { zoom: 11, center: {lat: centerLat, lng: centerLng}}
          
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
        
        for(var i =0; i<lats.length ; i++){
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: {lat: lats[i], lng: lngs[i]}, map: map});
        }
        
        
      }
      
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Flask you should use the `|tojson` filter when parsing template data on script tags as [described in the documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/templating/#standard-filters)

Change the html template in such way:

```
var lats = {{ templateData["latitudes"]|tojson }};
var lngs = {{ templateData["longitudes"]|tojson }};
```

Comment: I get the same error. and if I were to put {{ templateData["latitudes"]|tojson }} withing quotation marks like a String, it treats my var as a string so I can't perform list-like actions on it